# Android Studio / Gradle: run external tool before compilation

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android Studio project which consists of several modules.

Some of these modules need to run an external pre-processing tool before they're compiled. Plus, I also need to run another tool project-wide every time ANY module in the project is compiled

Unfortunately I'm new to Gradle and I'm being a bit overwhelmed by it. I've succesfully included a new Gradle script in my project by editing `settings.gradle` and I've written in it some Gradle tasks that run the tools I want to run, and that is fine.
But the problem is I don't understand how to hook them up so they get executed at the right moment.

Basically, I want to know how to edit my build scripts in order to:

A) **Always** run a certain gradle task **before** any module in the project is built. (If possible, I'd want this to run only once, in the sense that if I rebuild the entire project, which is composed of 20+ modules, I don't want it to run 20 times, just once. This is secondary tho, the main thing is that it needs to run every time any module in the project is built)
B) **Always** run a certain gradle task before a certain module is built. In other words: how do I edit the build script of a single, specific module in order to run a certain task before compilation? Note that in this case the invoked task needs to be able to know which gradle project invoked it, ie: which module is being compiled.

Hope the questions are clear, I'll clarify if necessary (as I said, I'm new to Gradle, hope I didn't mess up the terminology too much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to A is task dependency, I'm assuming when you say modules you mean subprojects, the ones you included in your settings.gradle.  If all these sub projects requires this task to run first, I would define the subprojects:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    task precompiletask() {
        println "Executing pre-compile task"
    }

    compileJava.dependsOn precompiletask
}
```

The second part of A you might get for free if you setup your task correctly and put inputs/outputs.  This is what gradle checks if it needs to rerun the task again or not.  If nothing change in inputs/outputs then it won't run the precompiletask and would skip it.

For part B, what I would do with this is find a common attributes between these projects and configure them:

```
configure(someProjects()) {
    // do whatever you want here to those projects
    // for example, set up pre compile task like the one above
}

def someProjects() {
        ext.someProjects = [] as Set

        ext.someProjects.addAll subprojects.findAll { Project aProject ->
            // filter here what's common with those projects
            // for example, all projects that have yml file
        }

        logger.debug("Some projects [{}]", ext.someProjects)

        ext.someProjects
}
```

Hope this helps, have fun :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it seems the "java" plugin conflicts with the android one: `Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.`

Comment: I'm not an android developer but you don't need the java plugin.  What I am trying to explain is you can get the task in android plugin that you want to perform a task before it execute and try to do the same thing:  androidtask.dependsOn precompiletask

Comment: Ok, I've kinda made part A work somehow. The order is not very reliable (it does run before the task I set as dependency, but not always "just before", sometimes earlier, but that's fine).

Comment: Part B is confusing me tho. First of all, "ext" doesn't exists, so using it breaks compilation. Secondly, I don't understand the relationship between "configure" and "someProjects". Is "configured" called once for each project returned by someProjects? Or only one time? But more importantly: if in "configure", like you suggest, I set a dependency for every project to the SAME task, wouldn't that task be executed only once (like in A) since the next times it would be up-to-date? For part B I need a task it to run every time one of  the sub-projects is built.

Comment: You can remove ext there and replace it with local variables.  In the configure statement, you are saying you want these projects to have all the task, dependencies, etc. you want to put inside the configuration.  It's a configuration so it is applied to every project.  Second part of your question, you would set up a task and make it depend on another task that you want to run before.  And you can reference current project attributes while the common task is running ex. task afterTask { println project.name } - this would execute in every project and print the project name

Comment: Thanks, don't have time now, will try it tomorrow, will accept if everything works.

Comment: I tested this a bit, however it seems that configure{} is never called. Where exactly should it be put? When is it invoked in the build lifecycle??

Comment: You can put it anywhere since it should be read during configuration phase.  You can put a println if you want to see if it's being executed

Comment: I tested it. It only runs (the configure{} method I mean) if I "rebuild" the project explicitly. It doesn't run if I just "make" (even if the sources have changed and thus part of the project is actually being recompiled). How can I set it up so that it runs every time?

Comment: where exactly did you put it?  can you include in the question?

Comment: I put it in a subproject which only consists of a build.gradle file, which I include from the main settings.gradle together with the other projects. This because I wanted to keep all my extra "tinkering" separated from the files generated by Android Studio itself. Should it instead be in the root project's build.gradle? I'll try as soon as I figure out how to call methods from one gradle project to another...

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Android Studio uses the "configuration on demand" feature, which only configures the project he thinks "need configuration". I solved by moving the configure{} block to the root project which is always configured no matter what.